# Why does Cosmos DB return 429 for a portion of requests despite not exceeding my manual set throughput

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

My Cosmos DB is using Shared Throughput across several containers. I have manually scaled up my Cosmos DB to 70,000 RU/s and I am currently running a large number of requests.

Looking in azure I can see that a portion of my requests are being throttled (returning 429).
To give an idea of numbers around 25k requests return 200 and around 5k requests return 429.
When I follow the warning in the azure portal that says my collection is exceeding provisioned throughput it shows the average throughput is 6.78k RU/s.

I don't understand why when I have 70,000 RU/s that my requests are being throttled when the average throughput is supposedly only 6,780 RU/s.

No other containers are being read or written to, all these requests are made against just one container.
As all these requests are to run a stored procedure they all have a Partition key supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is you have a hot partition that is reaching its allocated throughput before the other partitions are.

For a horizontally scalable database, throughput is allocated across physical partitions (computers) and data is partitioned using a partition key that basically acts as an address to route it to a specific computer to be stored.

Assume I have a collection with three partitions 1, 2, 3 and 30K RU/s. Each one of those will get 10K RU/s allocated to it. If I then run an operation that does a ton of operations on partition 2 and consumes all of it's 10K I'm going to get rate limited (429) even I don't touch partition 1 or 3.

To avoid this you need to pick a partition key that BOTH distributes data as evenly as possible during writes and ideally can also be used to answer queries within one or a small number (bounded) number of partitions, trying to avoid "fan out" queries where queries have to hit every partition.

Now for small collections that only reside on a single physical partition none of this matters because your data is all on a single physical partition. However, as the collection grows larger this causes issues which will prevent the database from scaling fully.

You can learn more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput)

Comment: Thanks for the response, if I go into the metrics tab for Cosmos, then to throughput and view the graphs provided there for my collection. There is one for Max consumed RU/s by each partition key range, and all bars are very similar in height, from 10k at the top to 7.5k at the lowest. Also the graph for Hot Partition Keys displays no data, no matter what i have selected. Any thoughts how I can dig deeper, though from a cursory look it doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: @NPhillips I'm not entirely sure as I haven't come across such a problem myself, but as far as I remember 10k RU is the limit for a partition. So I would guess that anything going over the 10k will result in a 429, thus I wouldn't exclude hot partitioning as the issue here.

Comment: @404 I think you are right, wasn't aware of the 10k RU limit on the partition but that would make sense. It seems our choice of partition is good for equally distributing the data, just we are trying to do too much with this stored procedure we are calling.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. 10K is the limit per partition. So in your case you are simply exhausting your provisioned throughput and need to provision more.